# Find the total number of ways in which $n$ distinct objects can be put into two different boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the total number of ways in which $n$ distinct objects can be put into two different boxes.

The given solution says that the answer is $2^n$. My doubt is why the answer can't be $n^2$, because the reasoning given is that they have "let the two boxes $B_1$ and $B_2$. For each of the $n$ objects, there are two choices, it is put in either box $1$ or box $2$. Therefore, by fundamental principle of counting, the total number of ways is $$\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \ldots}_{n~\text{times}} = 2^n$$
But according to this logic, can't I solve it like.... I choose $n$ different objects $N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4, \ldots, N_n$ and for each box I have $n$ choices so the answer will be $n \times n = n^2$.

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  Suppose $N=1$.  Then there are clearly two ways to do it, yes?  Either the object goes into Box $1$ or it goes into box $2$.  Taking $N=2$ won't help (since both methods give $2^2$), so now take $N=3$.  If you think there are $9$ ways to do it, list them.

Answer (score 3):

No, because you **don’t** choose $n$ different objects. You **have** $n$ different objects, and for each of them you choose which box is to contain that object.

If you insist on making choices for the boxes instead of for the objects, you can still solve the problem, but you’ll need more than the fundamental principle of counting. For Box $1$ there are not $n$ choices: what goes into Box $1$ is a subset of the set of $n$ objects, so you have $2^n$ choices, since a set of $n$ objects has $2^n$ different subsets. And after that you have only $1$ choice for Box $2$: it has to get all of the objects that are left. Thus, there are $2^n\cdot1=2^n$ ways to distribute the $n$ objects between the two boxes.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good reasoning, but there is one detail you miss when you state "for each box there are $n$ choices". This is not correct because once an object goes into box 1, there is only $n-1$ objectsfor box 2.  You can try making this approach work, but it needs more care than how it appears and will become very messy

The given solution is like this: For $n$ objects, label it "1" if it goes to box 1, and "2" if it goes to box 2.  Then each realization of putting objects into boxes is a string of "1"s and "2"s, example:
$$ \underbrace{1212...12}_{\text{n digits}} $$
(in this example, every other object goes into box 2). Now the number of ways of distributing objects to boxes equals the number of strings of length $n$ where each digit is either "1" or "2".  There are
$$ 2^n $$
such strings